# How can I see the quota (number of participants which can still register) under the manage events section?

Tags: civievent

How can I fetch **the number of participants(quota) who can register for an event** and 

the max number of participants in an event  if the event has not started on the manage events

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a BAO function in CiviCRM which returns the available slots for registration

```
CRM_Event_BAO_Participant::pendingToConfirmSpaces($eventId);
```

You can use api to get the max number of participant for an event

```
$result = civicrm_api3('Event', 'getvalue', [
  'return' => "max_participants",
  'id' => 1,
]);
```

To answer your question in detail, you canuse pagerun hook on event page and then get the variable assigned in smarty using `$rows = $page->get_template_vars('rows');` override the variable to add or remove values and then assign it back to smarty using `$page->assign('rows' $rows);`

HTH

Pradeep

Comment: How can I use this in manage events page,since it's not a form so probably can't use hook buildform, I was looking to get the value in the $row in the template where we have variables like $row.id, $row.repeat etc,if overriding tpl adding it in custom template section is not good practice,kindly suggest a way which is recommended,I am sorry if my question is silly

Comment: Updated the answer for your question